# Automated script to create/access an encrypted file with multiple recipients

Tags: encryption, openssl

My goal is to create an automated way of encrypting/decrypting some files using openssl. What I currently have are the public keys of the recipients (in PEM format) and the actual data I need to distribute.

Basically I want to create an `encrypt` script, that takes the data and the public keys and creates something, I distribute that thing and the recipients run a `decrypt` script and get the data. With one recipient this is easy enough (note that it has to be an automated script for decryption, just asking each recipient to decrypt manually the data is not enough). With multiple recipients...problems arise.

I have 2 approaches in mind, both of which fail to meet my requirements:

1. The `encrypt` script creates one encrypted file for each public key, the whole set of encrypted files is distributed and the `decrypt` script iterate through all of them and tries to decrypt them using the user's private key. This approach works, but the problem is that the user needs to enter his passphrase at each attempt (not too automated). The solution would be to find a way to either check if the file can be decrypted using the given private key and, if so, proceed to decrypting it or to avoid somehow asking each time for the passphrase (maybe something like ssh-agent).
2. Find a way to encrypt the file using all public keys so that everybody can decrypt it.

Comment: why openSSL? doesn't GPG do all this for you?

Comment: I already use the public keys for SSH access, so the solution I have in mind would integrate nicely in the existing system.